# Changing Permissions on Python Modules so I Don't Need to "sudo" My Python Script Calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudo, socks, urlopen

Is there a way to reconfigure all my Python3 modules from which I call certain utilities (i.e., urlopen) so that I no longer need to preface my Python3 script calls with "sudo", without having to rebuild my Ubuntu VM?

Example, with my script code as follows:

```
import socks
import socket
from urllib.request import urlopen
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

url_name1 = "http://www.google.com"
print("url name is : " + url_name1)
print("About to open the web page")
sleep(5)
webpage = urlopen(url_name1)
print("Web page opened successfully")
sleep(5)
html = webpage.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print("HTML extracted")
sleep(5)
```

Without prefacing my command with "sudo", the output looks like this:

```
$ python3 sample_script2.py
url name is : http://www.google.com
About to open the web page
1599238298 WARNING torsocks[29740]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons. (in tsocks_connect() at connect.c:193)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/socks.py", line 832, in connect
    super(socksocket, self).connect(proxy_addr)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1326, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1240, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1286, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1235, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1006, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 946, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 917, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/socks.py", line 100, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/socks.py", line 844, in connect
    raise ProxyConnectionError(msg, error)
socks.ProxyConnectionError: Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy 127.0.0.1:9050: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample_script2.py", line 14, in <module>
    webpage = urlopen(url_name1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1355, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1329, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy 127.0.0.1:9050: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted>
$
```

Adding "sudo" to the command yields the following:

```
jbottiger@ubuntu:~/DarkWeb$ sudo python3 sample_script2.py
[sudo] password for jbottiger: 
url name is : http://www.google.com
About to open the web page
Web page opened successfully
HTML extracted
Printing soup object text
Google(function(){window.google={kEI:'uHBSX4DxFqWd5wKA1KSAAw',kEXPI:'0,202162,1151585,5662,730,224,5105,206,3204,10,1226,364,1499,612,91,114,383,246,5,1354,648,3451,315,3,66,308,676,90,41,153,864,117,44,407,415,205,138,511,258,1119056,1197771,329496,13677,4855,32691,15248,861,28690,9188,8384,1326,3532,1362,9290,3028,4735,5,2649,8384,1808,4998,7933,5295,2054,920,873,4192,6430,7432,7095,4517,2778,919,2277,8,2796,1593,1279,2212,532,147,1103,842,515,1139,1,278,104,4258,312,1137,2,2063,606,2023,1733,43,521,1947,2229,93,328,1284,16,2927,2247,1819,1780,3227,2845,7,2903,2696,469,6286,4455,641,602,1847,3685,1742,4929,108,1456,1951,908,2,941,715,1899,2397,2650,4820,1704,473,1098,3,346,230,1835,4,4620,149,189,3313,743,1745,2220,32,4072,1661,4,498,1030,2304,1236,271,874,405,1860,2393,1791,52,2377,464,459,1201,354,4067,153,882,1316,3,610,1498,1172,1426,69,644,1,1388,386,196,2811,935,818,690,1542,1639,533,2,425,862,1019,189,56,264,198,25,887,564,464,217,8,431,30,130,340,832,2287,181,223,1314,23,1102,655,990,52,535,1239,1257,254,1209,35,591,379,850,437,2,16,6,86,197,22,689,6,632,146,411,108,1,958,360,115,2,93,200,1189,157,1938,792,80,4,26,500,37,891,820,765,286,63,299,60,696,86,1,353,290,52,56,3,403,11,89,685,78,1,217,513,92,383,617,363,1393,5765060,8800593,1323,549,333,444,1,2,80,1,900,896,1,9,2,2551,1,748,141,795,10,553,1,4265,1,1,2,1017,9,305,3299,248,283,527,32,1,10,2,3,1,6,1,14,9,1,2,2,4,4,12,6,10,8,2,35,12,2,1,23959867,53,2704777',kBL:'QdLX'};google.sn='webhp';google.kHL='ru';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var c;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(c=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return c||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var c=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(c=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return c};google.ml=function(){return null};google.time=function(){return Date.now()};google.log=function(a,c,b,d,g){if(b=google.logUrl(a,c,b,d,g)){a=new Image;var e=google.lc,f=google.li;e[f]=a;a.onerror=a.onload=a.onabort=function(){delete e[f]};google.vel&&google.vel.lu&&google.vel.lu(b);a.src=b;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,c,b,d,g){var e="",f=google.ls||"";b||-1!=c.search("&ei=")||(e="&ei="+google.getEI(d),-1==c.search("&lei=")&&(d=google.getLEI(d))&&(e+="&lei="+d));d="";!b&&google.cshid&&-1==c.search("&cshid=")&&"slh"!=a&&(d="&cshid="+google.cshid);b=b||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+c+e+f+"&zx="+google.time()+d;/^http:/i.test(b)&&"https:"==window.location.protocol&&(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:b,glmm:1}),b="");return b};}).call(this);(function(){google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){if(a)var c=a.id;else{do c=Math.random();while(google.y[c])}google.y[c]=[a,b];return!1};google.lm=[];google.plm=function(a){google.lm.push.apply(google.lm,a)};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};}).call(this);google.f={};(function(){
document.documentElement.addEventListener("submit",function(b){var a;if(a=b.target){var c=a.getAttribute("data-submitfalse");a="1"==c||"q"==c&&!a.elements.q.value?!0:!1}else a=!1;a&&(b.preventDefault(),b.stopPropagation())},!0);document.documentElement.addEventListener("click",function(b){var a;a:{for(a=b.target;a&&a!=document.documentElement;a=a.parentElement)if("A"==a.tagName){a="1"==a.getAttribute("data-nohref");break a}a=!1}a&&b.preventDefault()},!0);}).call(this);
var a=window.location,b=a.href.indexOf("#");if(0<=b){var c=a.href.substring(b+1);/(^|&)q=/.test(c)&&-1==c.indexOf("#")&&a.replace("/search?"+c.replace(/(^|&)fp=[^&]*/g,"")+"&cad=h")};#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}
body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#36c}.q{color:#00c}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}body{background:#fff;color:#000}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#36c}a:visited{color:#551a8b}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #999 #999 #ccc;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}#fll a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#ccc}.lst:focus{outline:none}.tiah{width:458px}(function(){var src='/images/nav_logo229.png';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}
if (!iesg){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}
}
})();Поиск Картинки Карты Play YouTube Новости Почта Диск Ещё »История веб-поиска | Настройки | Войти (function(){var id='tsuid1';document.getElementById(id).onclick = function(){var s = document.createElement('script');s.src = this.getAttribute('data-script-url');(document.getElementById('xjsc')||document.body).appendChild(s);};})();(function(){var id='tsuid2';document.getElementById(id).onclick = function(){if (this.form.q.value){this.checked = 1;if (this.form.iflsig)this.form.iflsig.disabled = false;}
else top.location='/doodles/';};})();Расширенный поиск(function(){var a,b="1";if(document&&document.getElementById)if("undefined"!=typeof XMLHttpRequest)b="2";else if("undefined"!=typeof ActiveXObject){var c,d,e=["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];for(c=0;d=e[c++];)try{new ActiveXObject(d),b="2"}catch(h){}}a=b;if("2"==a&&-1==location.search.indexOf("&gbv=2")){var f=google.gbvu,g=document.getElementById("gbv");g&&(g.value=a);f&&window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=f},0)};}).call(this);Рекламные программыРешения для бизнесаВсё о GoogleGoogle.ru© 2020 - Конфиденциальность - Условия(function(){window.google.cdo={height:0,width:0};(function(){var a=window.innerWidth,b=window.innerHeight;if(!a||!b){var c=window.document,d="CSS1Compat"==c.compatMode?c.documentElement:c.body;a=d.clientWidth;b=d.clientHeight}a&&b&&(a!=google.cdo.width||b!=google.cdo.height)&&google.log("","","/client_204?&atyp=i&biw="+a+"&bih="+b+"&ei="+google.kEI);}).call(this);})();(function(){var u='/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en.6FZeP6lo3MI.O/m\x3dsb_he,d/am\x3dAJ5gcw/d\x3d1/rs\x3dACT90oG6N5VH73PFnXBwBd2MrAZnJY6t4Q';
setTimeout(function(){var b=document;var a="SCRIPT";"application/xhtml+xml"===b.contentType&&(a=a.toLowerCase());a=b.createElement(a);a.src=u;google.timers&&google.timers.load&&google.tick&&google.tick("load","xjsls");document.body.appendChild(a)},0);})();(function(){window.google.xjsu='/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en.6FZeP6lo3MI.O/m\x3dsb_he,d/am\x3dAJ5gcw/d\x3d1/rs\x3dACT90oG6N5VH73PFnXBwBd2MrAZnJY6t4Q';})();function _DumpException(e){throw e;}
function _F_installCss(c){}
(function(){google.jl={dw:false,em:[],emw:false,lls:'default',pdt:0,snet:true,uwp:true};})();(function(){var pmc='{\x22d\x22:{},\x22sb_he\x22:{\x22agen\x22:true,\x22cgen\x22:true,\x22client\x22:\x22heirloom-hp\x22,\x22dh\x22:true,\x22dhqt\x22:true,\x22ds\x22:\x22\x22,\x22ffql\x22:\x22ru\x22,\x22fl\x22:true,\x22host\x22:\x22google.com\x22,\x22isbh\x22:28,\x22jsonp\x22:true,\x22msgs\x22:{\x22cibl\x22:\x22&#1059;&#1076;&#1072;&#1083;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100; &#1087;&#1086;&#1080;&#1089;&#1082;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081; &#1079;&#1072;&#1087;&#1088;&#1086;&#1089;\x22,\x22dym\x22:\x22&#1042;&#1086;&#1079;&#1084;&#1086;&#1078;&#1085;&#1086;, &#1074;&#1099; &#1080;&#1084;&#1077;&#1083;&#1080; &#1074; &#1074;&#1080;&#1076;&#1091;:\x22,\x22lcky\x22:\x22&#1052;&#1085;&#1077; &#1087;&#1086;&#1074;&#1077;&#1079;&#1105;&#1090;!\x22,\x22lml\x22:\x22&#1055;&#1086;&#1076;&#1088;&#1086;&#1073;&#1085;&#1077;&#1077;...\x22,\x22oskt\x22:\x22&#1069;&#1082;&#1088;&#1072;&#1085;&#1085;&#1072;&#1103; &#1082;&#1083;&#1072;&#1074;&#1080;&#1072;&#1090;&#1091;&#1088;&#1072;\x22,\x22psrc\x22:\x22&#1069;&#1090;&#1086;&#1090; &#1079;&#1072;&#1087;&#1088;&#1086;&#1089; &#1073;&#1099;&#1083; &#1091;&#1076;&#1072;&#1083;&#1077;&#1085; &#1080;&#1079; &#1074;&#1072;&#1096;&#1077;&#1081; \\u003Ca href\x3d\\\x22/history\\\x22\\u003E&#1080;&#1089;&#1090;&#1086;&#1088;&#1080;&#1080; &#1074;&#1077;&#1073;-&#1087;&#1086;&#1080;&#1089;&#1082;&#1072;\\u003C/a\\u003E\x22,\x22psrl\x22:\x22&#1059;&#1076;&#1072;&#1083;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;\x22,\x22sbit\x22:\x22&#1055;&#1086;&#1080;&#1089;&#1082; &#1087;&#1086; &#1082;&#1072;&#1088;&#1090;&#1080;&#1085;&#1082;&#1077;\x22,\x22srch\x22:\x22&#1055;&#1086;&#1080;&#1089;&#1082; &#1074; Google\x22},\x22ovr\x22:{},\x22pq\x22:\x22\x22,\x22refpd\x22:true,\x22rfs\x22:[],\x22sbpl\x22:16,\x22sbpr\x22:16,\x22scd\x22:10,\x22stok\x22:\x22WKTHIsN6ufJvVLrcm5Yf_IkFoE0\x22,\x22uhde\x22:false}}';google.pmc=JSON.parse(pmc);})(); 
jbottiger@ubuntu:~/DarkWeb$
```

Comment: The `torsocks` message is surely significant: how does that come into play?

Comment: @DavisHerring:  I'm writing a script such that I can parse and extract data from the dark web.

Answer (score 0):

I posed this question to my professor who recommended that I preface my python3 command with "torsocks" after enabling torsocks on my Ubuntu VM (must have torsocks installed and configured prior to running the script).

After that, remove the following two statements from the script.

```
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

Now when I enter:  "torsocks python3 <script_name>.py", I do not receive these errors anymore, including when trying to open a dark-web page.

According to my professor, Dr. Terrence O'Connor, PhD (Florida Institute of Technology), both my original approach of specifying a proxy (i.e., tor) in my script and using torsocks to tunnel traffic of a specific command (i.e., "python3" in my case) are viable methods of connecting to the ToR network via the proxy service om my Ubuntu VM.  It appears as if the second method recommended by Dr. O'Connor worked better than the first one.

Comment: Perhaps you were proxying twice, which Tor disallows (because of the potentiality it mentions)?